# Read XML data using specified DTD

Tags: jsp, xml-parsing, dtd, xml

> I am working on web project where i need to read xml file data using
>   dtd file.
>
> As in core java we can do this by using DefaultTreeModel this will
>   does the task simpler.
>
> So there is any API provided in jsp/servlet to read xml data using dtd
>   file.
>
> Here is screen shot of my **interpro.xml** file

[image]

**intepro.dtd**

[image]

Tree look like this,

[image]

I searched but not getting clear solution to read xml data using dtd to create tree.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  What do you mean by "read[ing] xml data using dtd"?  Why do you care whether the DTD is being used or not?  It looks like you are building a tree to represent the XML document instance, not (for example) a tree to represent the document grammaer embodied in the DTD.  The instance tree will not be affected by the DTD, unless there are default attribute values in the document instance, which your tree drawing software is ignoring.

Comment: @C. M. Sperberg-McQueen i am trying to read xml file using SAX parser but i has some limitations because it directly giving all nodes(elements) available so it is hard to differentiate parent and child elements.That's why i have posted this question.Have you know anything about this?